# Basic Queries in Firebase and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I have a Firebase that looks like this:

```
{
  "jobs" : {
    "-Jnbc60FQGiKUubz0u6e" : {
      "Description" : "The sink has a leaky faucet!",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:4"
    },
    "-Jnbc60FQGiKUubz0u6e" : {
      "Description" : "The microwave is broken",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:6"
    },
    "-Jnbc60FQGiKUubz0u6e" : {
      "Description" : "Window Cracked",
      "uid" : "simplelogin:6"
    },
  }
}
```

I'm trying to understand querying in Firebase but am getting really confused.

What I want to do is the equivalent of this SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE uid="simplelogin:6"`

Here is where i'm at in Angular:

```
var firebase = new Firebase(firebaseURL);
var jobs = firebase.child('jobs');

// BIND FIREBASE DATA TO LOCAL VARIALBES FOR 3 WAY DATA BINDING
$firebaseObject(jobs).$bindTo($scope, 'Jobs');
```

That pulls in all of the jobs which I can access, but I need to filter it somehow, and then bind that variable to the `$scope.Jobs` variable.

How would that be accomplished?

Comment: See also:  https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have some suggestions:

- Check out the [Firebase Query documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/). Specifically,

  - [`.orderByChild()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbychild.html)
  - [`.equalTo()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html)
- And the [Querying Data section of 'Retrieving Data' in the Web Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

So, you can accomplish your goal by combining `.orderByChild()` and `.equalTo()` like so:

```js
var firebaseRef = new Firebase(firebaseURL);

var userId = "simplelogin:6";
var jobs = firebaseRef.child("jobs").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(userId);

var jobsObject = $firebaseObject(jobs);
jobsObject.$bindTo($scope, "jobs").then(function(){
  console.log("jobsObject bound to $scope.jobs");
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how orderByChild(userId) filters out to only the userId, where is uid even being referenced?

Comment: Great! Sorry about the initial confusion.